# How to move global script declaration from HTML into JS file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

my React.js 18 index.html has google maps api declaration to use it across whole app

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXX&libraries=places"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but I do not want to show XXXXXX api key and store it in repo. I want to pull it somewhere from config file (secrets).
So assume I need to move this script declaration somewhere into JS file.
How do I properly do it?

Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth: this is a public key, so there's no security benefit to hiding it, if that's your concern. It's sent with every API request anyway, so people can still find it just by hitting F12. If it *was* a secret key, it shouldn't be in your frontend JS at all.

Comment: putting a key in a script file won't protect it if the browser needs it to make the request

Comment: I want to hide it at least in my repo at GitHub..

Comment: If you want to load the API key from JS, you will need to use one of the alternative ways of loading the script [documented here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api) (which seems to be the recommended approach anyway).